# Using powershell, how do I check for “Log on as service” to an account for remote server?

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting

I want to know whether a specific user with details like username, password, ip, hostname;
Using powershell script, how do I check for “Log on as service” to an account for remote server ?

```
function Get-UserRightsGrantedToAccount([String]$UserName, [String]$Password, [String]$ComputerAddress, [String]$HostName) {
      $Credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($UserName, (ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force))
   // code to check User Right "SeServiceLogonRight"
}
```

Comment: The target user - is that a local account on the remote server or a network/domain account?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen   UserName belongs to HostName user grooup. Means userName is local to remote machine.